# Compare two Collections in MongoDB and show the differences

Tags: node.js, mongodb, comparison

I'm trying to compare two collections in mongodb. I have `Collection A` and `Collection B` and I only want to show the Differences. How is this done? I thought it could be done with the Aggregation Framework but I did not get the expected values. I just want to see which Document in `Collection A` is not the same as in `Collection B`.

Collection: A

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("x"),
    "p" : [ 
        {
            "t" : 1,
            "p" : 123
        }, 
        {
            "t" : 2,
            "p" : 123
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("y"),
    "p" : [ 
        {
            "t" : 1,
            "p" : 234
        }, 
        {
            "t" : 2,
            "p" : 234
        }
    ]
}
```

Collection: B

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("x"),
    "p" : [ 
        {
            "t" : 1,
            "p" : 123
        }, 
        {
            "t" : 2,
            "p" : 538458 // OTHER VALUE HERE
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("y"),
    "p" : [ 
        {
            "t" : 1,
            "p" : 234
        }, 
        {
            "t" : 2,
            "p" : 234
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: one solution over top of my head is you fetch data from both collections and compare them. I would recommend do this check at the time of insertion

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, too, but I don't know how this could be done in a way that's working efficiantly.

Comment: what is your document size? if it is not very large then it's just a 2 find({}) operations, rest is iteration over the list.

Comment: the collections got about 16k documents. Is there an efficient way to iterate through the lists and compare them?

Answer (score 0):

You could export each collection by using `mongoexport`, this will create a file with all the documents, but make sure you omit the `_id` (documents maybe identical but will have different ids):
`mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name | sed '/"_id":/s/"_id":[^,]*,//' > file_name.json`

Then you can compare the two files using `diff`.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the differences by mongodb itself?

Comment: I don't think there is any built in function in mongoDB that allows such comparison, and looping through entire collection with some basic js `loops` would be  slow and imperfect expecially if you have lot of nesting.